# returning derivatives with boost odeint

Tags: c++, boost, ode

I  am using boost odeint to integrate 2n coupled equations. My basic question is quite general. How can I return not only the states x_i for each time step using the observer but also return the derivatives d(x_i)/dt? I know how to return the state or some function of the state at a given time, but I don't know how to return something which is a function of states at a given time and at times before.

To be more concrete, here is a simplified version of my code.

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> matrixd;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
using namespace std;

struct k_ring
{
    int     m_N;

    k_ring( int N = 5 ) :
    m_N ( N ) {}

    void operator() (const matrixd &x, matrixd &dxdt, const double )
    {
        matrixd loc_coup( m_N, 2, 0 );
    
        for( int i=0 ; i<m_N ; ++i ){
            for( int k=0; k<m_N ; ++k ){
                if(abs(k-i) <= 30 && dist > 0){
                    loc_coup(i,0) += sin( x(i,0) - x(k,0) + 0.45 );
                    loc_coup(i,1) += sin( x(i,1) - x(k,1) + 0.45 );
                }
            }
            dxdt(i,0) = - (0.1/61)*loc_coup(i,0) + 0.2*sin( x(i,1) - x(i,0) );
            dxdt(i,1) = - (0.1/61)*loc_coup(i,1) - 0.2*sin( x(i,1) - x(i,0) );
        }
    }
};

struct observer
{
    const double    m_sim_time;

    observer( const float &sim_time ) :
    m_sim_time( sim_time ) {}

    void operator()( matrixd &x, double t)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < x.size1(); ++i){
            cout << t/m_sim_time << '\t' << x(i,0) << '\t' << '\n';
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    double dt = 0.01;
    int n = 256;
    double sim_time = 100.0;
    matrixd x( n , 2 , 0. );

    k_ring system(n);

    observer obs(sim_time);

    integrate_const(runge_kutta4< matrixd >(), system, x, 0.0, sim_time, dt, boost::ref( obs ));
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I define psi(i) = x(i,1)-x(i,0), how could I calculate the derivative d psi(i)/dt at each time step?

Comment: There does not seem to be any provision in the library structure. So you would have to call the `system` function from inside the observer to get the derivatives values for the state. That is, pass the `system` object via the constructor of the observer, provide the return object and just call the function and evaluate the results.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. So if I’ve understood correctly I would need to call the system twice, once in the observer as well as once outside the observer as usual. How would I pass the system object via the constructor of the observer? Something like observer(&system) :  … { … } ?

Comment: Yes. Note that `system` is called 4 times for every RK4 step, you duplicate the first stage. There does not appear a mechanism to avoid that. Short of implementing that yourself in the stepper class, this can not be avoided. And yes to the general shape of the constructor.

Comment: So I’ve been trying to implement these ideas, but I’m really stuck. 
In the constructor of the observer I tried 
observer( void (*system) ( double ), const float &sim_time ) : 
And in the main I tried
observer obs(&system.operator(), data_out, sim_time, l_two);
I got back the error Cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function, which I could overcome by making the function in system a static function, but doesn’t this function need to be non-static?

Comment: To use system in the observer it seems like I would need the observer to be a function of dxdt, i.e. operator()( matrixd &x, matrixd &dxdt, double t), but I’m not sure if I can just simply make the observer a function of dxdt, and if I could, wouldn’t I just simply be able to print dxdt and not use the system in the constructor at all?

Comment: In the above paragraph I meant to write "observer( void (*system) ( int ), const float &sim_time ) :"  and "obs(&system.operator(), sim_time);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal example on what I mean with my comment

> You would have to call the system function from inside the observer to get the derivatives values for the state. That is, pass the system object via the constructor of the observer, provide the return object and just call the function and evaluate the results.

This is done via the `m_odefun` and `m_dxdt` fields. The example uses the standard vanderPol oscillator which is a second-order DE giving a first-order system with 2-dimensional state vectors. (The observer does not need to be templated, this was just done to follow the `odeint` template practice.)

```cpp
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
typedef boost::array<double, 2> vec;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
using namespace std;

struct vanderPol
{
    double m_mu;

    vanderPol( double mu = 3 ) : m_mu ( mu ) {}

    void operator() (const vec &x, vec &dxdt, const double )
    {
        dxdt[0] = x[1];
        dxdt[1] = -m_mu*(x[0]*x[0]-1)*x[1]-x[0];
    }
};

template<class system>
struct observer
{
    vec m_dxdt;
    system m_odefun;
    observer(system odefun) : m_odefun(odefun) { }

    void operator()( vec &x, double t)
    {
        cout << "at t=" << t << "\tx: " << x[0] << '\t'  << x[1];
        m_odefun(x, m_dxdt, t);
        cout << "\tdxdt: " << m_dxdt[0] << '\t'  << m_dxdt[1] << '\n';
        
    }
};


int main()
{
    double dt = 0.01;
    double sim_time = 1.0;
    vec x = {0.0, 1.7};

    vanderPol system(1.3);

    observer< vanderPol > obs(system);

    integrate_const(runge_kutta4< vec >(), system, x, 0.0, sim_time, dt, boost::ref( obs ));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: I have one last small question. If I replace all the vec in your code with matrixd more along the lines of the code in the question ( matrixd x(2, 1) ) then I get back a bad_index error at the line m_odefun(x, m_dxdt, t). It seems like the index should be the same as that for vec. Is there a simple fix/ explanation for this?

Comment: Did you replace the element syntax from `[i]` to `(i,0)` in all places? There should be not much difference, both headers implement vectors. You would have to explicitly initialize `matrixd m_dxdt(2,1,0);`, the system function assumes that the memory for the vector data already is allocated.

Comment: Yep that's it. I hadn't explicitly initialised `matrixd m_dxdt(2,1,0)`. If I use `observer(system odefun, matrixd x) : m_odefun(odefun) , m_dxdt(x) { }` then it works as before. Thank you